# Installing Unity 4.6.1 error: No SDK found

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

Since installing Unity 4.6.1 I have been having an SDK version problem.

When I download the SDK all I get is the "tools, platforms, add-ons folders and AVD Manager.exe and SDK Manager.exe.

When I point Unity to this folder it still says no SDK found.

I tried copying these files and replacing the same ones in my SDK that did work.

How do I set the SDK file up?

Answer (score 1):

Point it to the root folder of Android SDK which you got after unzipping the bundle.

Also, see this: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/TroubleShootingAndroid.html

EDIT:
After seeing the edits to my post, I think it makes sense to put this info out here for better visibility.
Anyone with OP's problems, read this:

There's a zip available if you don't want the Android Studio bundle. Here: developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Other

But you don't need to download the whole thing again and again. Just fire up the sdk manager, tick mark the packages you need to update (just select the core packages, exclude docs and samples and sources and emulator system images), accept their licenses, and just install.

Also, it is not necessary to update the Android SDK everytime Unity asks you to do so. Just hit in `continue` as many times as is required. Your build will continue.

Comment: Hi Thank you for the reply! Ok let me explain a bit more. I had a SDK folder and it was working fine. After installing Unity 4.6.1 It said I needed the new version. So I went to the Android dev site and there are no SDK downloads. Just the Android Studio and Android tools. I downloaded the tools but not working. Did Android do away with the ADT Bundle? Im not sure what to download to get the SDK.

Comment: Actually, there's a zip available if you don't want the Android Studio bundle. Here: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Other

But you don't need to download the whole thing again and again. Just fire up the sdk manager, tick mark the packages you need to update (just select the core packages, exclude docs and samples and sources and emulator system images), accept their licenses, and just install.

Comment: Also, you could force Unity to build the APK with your current version of Android SDK. Just hit on `continue` as many times as is needed.

Comment: Again thank you for the reply's I really do appreciate it.

Ok I downloaded the android-sdk_r24.0.2-windows.zip But when I point to it Unity still askes for the SDK dir. Also tried the SDK manager from Eclipse, It doesn't want to open. Running Window 8.1 64.

Comment: You don't point it to the zip file, but the android sdk folder after you unzip it. Also, I tell again, use the SDK Manager.exe to update (just double click it, you don't have to use Eclipse to open it). You can't afford to download the sdk zip everytime Unity wants it updated.

Comment: Ok The Manager finally started up, not sure why it took so long. Busy updating now. Thank you so much for the sound advice. I didn't know about the update manager. You really helped a lot, thank you so much. Will let you know when the update is done :)

Comment: Got SDK manager working. Thank you for the help all is working as expected :)

Answer (score 1):

Window-->Preferences-->Android-->
SDK Location: C:\CI\android-sdk-windows\tools-->then SDK Location: C:\CI\android-sdk-windows-->Apply-->
List show: 
Target Name      Vendor                         Platform   API Level
Android 5.0.1    Andriod Open Source Project    5.0.1      21
Google APIs      Google Inc.                    5.0.1      21

-->OK